# jquery ui, can't acess object variables from within the draggable function

Tags: jquery, user-interface, undefined, draggable

I am making a game in jquery, and wanted the player to be able to drag around objects. However it seems i am unable to access the variables from the draggable functions.
Here is the relevant code:

```
Current.Hej=1;
Current.draggable({
drag: function(event, ui){
    console.log($(this).Hej);
}
});
```

And it returns undefined. I have tried various things, like calling the actula ID of the object rather than  $(this), and it still returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$(this)`. You initialize a new jQuery object which is not the same as Current. It only contains the same element. You could do `console.log(Current.Hej);`, however I strongly recommend refactoring your code so you don't have to set additional data like this.

You could for example use [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: thanks, but it seems strange when you sat $(this) initializes a new object. Because the problem is only under draggable. Thanks for the link nevertheless, that should solve the problem ^^